# How to create a workflow which should trigger when creating a PR to main from branches starting with name BASH?

Tags: github-actions

want to create a workflow which should trigger when creating a PR to main from branches starting with name BASH

Created with below but not working.

```
name: Validate PR

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'BASH*'
```